# How to initialize linked list whose node is matrix?

Tags: c++, linked-list

In c++, can I initialize a linked list whose nodes are the matrix? Can I use std::list< double[2][2]> mylist, 
which means every node in the linked list is a 2*2 matrix?

If I cannot initialize like this, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Why not try it and see ?

Comment: @PaulR I tried std::list < double > mylist and it works but when I tried std::list< double[2][2] > mylist, there is a long error.

Comment: OK - that would be good information to put in your question.

Comment: You cannot store C arrays in STL containers. Elements stored in STL containers must be assignable and copyable, arrays are neither.

Comment: C arrays aren't even `Erasable`, since the pseudo-destructor call for them isn't well-formed. If you are using C++11, consider `std::array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your matrix in a struct or class, e.g.

```
#include <list>

struct D {
    double a[2][2];
};

int main()
{
    std::list<D> mylist;

    D d = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };

    mylist.push_back(d);
}
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1785efd41f550554)